# concatenating error in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, attr

I have this problem with my `jquery` code. I need it to concatenate a `jquery` variable value to an an html attribute `href`. It however keeps returning `[object%20Object]` in the place of the actual variable value.

Here is my jquery.

```
var searchValname = $("input#name"); 
var alink = $("a#name");
alink.click(function(){ 
    alink.attr("href","searchDBfiltered.php?type=hospitalnumber&val=" + searchValname);
});
```

it is expected to return `searchDBfiltered.php?type=hospitalnumber&val= (variable value)`. It instead shows `[object%20Object]`. What could be wrong please? I have googled this to no help.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're currently trying to insert the actual #name object into the link when you really want the value.

```
var searchValname = $("input#name").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects are just that - Objects. When you concatenate an object to a string, an implicit `toString()` is called which, unless something has defined otherwise, will return `"[object Object]"`.

If you're trying to concatenate the value of the input, you should be using `.val()`:

```
alink.attr("href","searchDBfiltered.php?type=hospitalnumber&val=" +
    searchValname.val());
//               ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the first line :

```
var searchValname = $("input#name").val(); 
var alink = $("a#name");
alink.click(function(){ 
alink.attr("href","searchDBfiltered.php?type=hospitalnumber&val=" + searchValname);
});
```

Comment: That was my mistake. totally forgot bout the val();. I am new to jquery by the way. Thanks very much.